# Stop image resize using Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries

Does anybody have an idea why my media queries is not working. I want my image to stay to 1000px (which is the original image size) when it detect the screen 1000px or more.

Here's my code:

CSS:

```
    .header
    {
          height:100px;
          width:100%;
     }
    .header img
    { 
          width:100%;
     }

    @media screen and (min-width:1000px;)
      {

        .header
         {
           height:100px; 
           width:1000px; 
         }
        .header img
         {
           width:1000px;
         }  
      }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="header">
 <img src="/common/media/images/some-image.jpg" />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use css's `max-width` to set the max size of the image. Then it cannot be bigger than the original size.

So remove your media query, and simply use this:

```
.header {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}

.header img { 
    width:100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 100% with

.header img
    { 
          **max-width:1000px;**
     }